# Felix bundles - org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to acquire global lock for resolve

Tags: osgi, aem, apache-felix

I am running an instance of AEM 6.1 and am having problems installing bundles.  I am installing the bundles via Maven (probably not related, but not ruling it out).

Periodically a bundle will not start when it is installed.  I get the following stack trace related to the bundle that did not start.

```
*ERROR* [Background Update org.mybundle.bundle (392)] org.apache.felix.http.jetty Cannot install or update bundle from /media/ephemeral0/aemtmp/install24
98177112217878414.tmp (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to acquire global lock for resolve.)
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to acquire global lock for resolve.
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4101)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2114)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.updateBundle(Felix.java:2481)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.update(BundleImpl.java:995)
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.core.UpdateHelper.doRun(UpdateHelper.java:60)
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.core.BaseUpdateInstallHelper.doRun(BaseUpdateInstallHelper.java:93)
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.core.UpdateHelper.doRun(UpdateHelper.java:70)
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.core.BaseUpdateInstallHelper.run(BaseUpdateInstallHelper.java:123)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Has anyone seen this issue and know of a solution?